# No resume is printed out on my ListIterator case

Tags: java

I have written following code for using the List Iterator function, why no result is printed out, can anyone tell me what is wrong ? thanks.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ListIterator;



public class MyTest {

    public static void main (String[] args){

        ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
        myList.add("Apple");
        myList.add("Orange");
        myList.add("Banana");
        myList.add("Grape");
        myList.add("Water Melon");


        ListIterator<String> itr = myList.listIterator();

        while(itr.hasNext());
        System.out.println(itr.next());

        while(itr.hasPrevious());
        System.out.println(itr.previous());

    }

}
```

Comment: remove the semicolon after `while();` with `;` while body is empty so print is not included in loop body

Comment: Remove the semicolon from while loop

Comment: You should always use `{` and `}` (at least when you seem to have a bug in your code) to avoid these mistakes ;)

Comment: Remember Iterator.hasNext() returns true if the iteration has more elements. (In other words, returns true if next() would return an element rather than throwing an exception.) So it is not moving the head/cursor ahead and just returning if next element present or not. Hence causing infinite loop in your case.

Answer (score 3):

Change your while loop into this:

```
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(itr.next());
}

while(itr.hasPrevious()) {
    System.out.println(itr.previous());
}
```

See how semicolons are there.

Comment: Apple
Orange
Banana
Grape
Water Melon
Water Melon
Grape
Banana
Orange
Apple
This is the output after running above code

Answer (score 0):

```
  while(itr.hasNext());   // semilcolon here
  System.out.println(itr.next());

  while(itr.hasPrevious()); // semilcolon here
  System.out.println(itr.previous());
```

both while loops have empty statements because of those semicolons  . your code is thus running infinity.

use `{}` for your loops.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to add along with the information in other answers is that indentation is a powerful tool. You can make out that something is wrong by seeing indentation of your code if your code is indented properly.

This is what you have:

```
while(itr.hasNext());  
System.out.println(itr.next());
```

You can see that both statements are on the same level, if the 2nd statement was supposed to be running within the `while` loop, it should have been one level deep like here:

```
while(itr.hasNext())
    System.out.println(itr.next());
```

The above is what you would get if you didn't have the `;` at the end of the `while` statement.